# Getting value of toggled select fields in jquery

Tags: jquery, onchange

Im trying to get the value of a selection based upon a previous on change selection. This is the initial html that shows or hides the next select:

```
<div class="selectOptionCat">
    <select class="categoryName1 changeFields" name="option">
        <option value="1">One</option>
        <option value="2">Two</option>
        <option value="3">Three</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Depending on the above selection another selection hides or shows using the change function:

```
<div id="firstOption" class="selectOptionsWrapper variableSelector">
    <select class="chipsTaste1 changeFields" name="optionA">
        <option value="1a">One A</option>
        <option value="2a">Two A</option>                   
    </select>
</div>

<div id="secondOption" class="selectOptionsWrapper variableSelector">
    <select class="chipsTaste1 changeFields" name="optionB">
        <option value="1b">One A</option>
        <option value="2b">Two A</option>                   
    </select>
</div>

<div id="thirdOption" class="selectOptionsWrapper variableSelector">
    <select class="chipsTaste1 changeFields" name="optionC">
        <option value="1c">One A</option>
        <option value="2c">Two A</option>                   
    </select>
</div>
```

However it is only returning me the values of the firstOption.

js part:

```
function getValues() {
    // can only get the value of the firstOption???
    var chipsTaste = $('.chipsTaste1').val();
}

    $(".wrapper").on('change', '.categoryName1', function() {

        $('.variableSelector').css('display','none');

        if ($(".categoryName1 ").val() == "1") {
           $('#firstOption').css('display','block');
        }else if($(".categoryName1 ").val() == "2") {
           $('#secondOption').css('display','block');
        }else($(".categoryName1 ").val() == "3") {
           $('#thirdOption').css('display','block');
        }   
    });
```

The two html parts above are wrapped in a div with class .wrapper
The getValues function is inside a click function later in the script.
Any help is much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [**`val()`**](http://api.jquery.com/val/) method returns the value of the first matched element, whether it's hidden or not.

To show the value of the visible `select` only, change this:

```
var chipsTaste = $('.chipsTaste1').val();
```

… to this:

```
var chipsTaste = $('.chipsTaste1:visible').val();
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/drtqfw3p/1/)